# Php curl multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql, curl, preg-match

i would like to open all the page ids of the website starting with http://website.com/page.php?id=1 and ending with id=1000

take the data via preg_match and record it somewhere or .txt or .sql

bellow is the curl function i'm using at the moment please kindly advise the full code that will get this job done.

```
function curl($url)
    {

    $POSTFIELDS = 'name=admin&password=guest&submit=save';
    $reffer = "http://google.com/";
    $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)";
    $cookie_file_path = "C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/spiders/cookie/cook"; // Please set your Cookie File path. This file must have CHMOD 777 (Full Read / Write Option).

    $ch = curl_init();  // Initialize a CURL session. 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  // The URL to fetch. You can also set this when initializing a session with curl_init(). 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); // The contents of the "User-Agent: " header to be used in a HTTP request. 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); //TRUE to do a regular HTTP POST. This POST is the normal application/x-www-form-urlencoded kind, most commonly used by HTML forms. 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$POSTFIELDS); //The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation. 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  // TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly. 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // TRUE to follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part of the HTTP header (note this is recursive, PHP will follow as many "Location: " headers that it is sent, unless CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS is set). 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $reffer); //The contents of the "Referer: " header to be used in a HTTP request. 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path); // The name of the file containing the cookie data. The cookie file can be in Netscape format, or just plain HTTP-style headers dumped into a file. 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path); // The name of a file to save all internal cookies to when the connection closes. 
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;

   }
```

Comment: `full code that will get this job done` get what done?

Comment: i would like to open all the page ids of the website starting with http://website.com/page.php?id=1 and ending with id=1000

take the data via preg_match and record it somewhere or .txt or .sql

Comment: apart from the curl() function what have you tried so far?

Comment: @GeorgeSamarguliani Is this question resolved?  if so, please award Subgeo's answer with the green tick.  If it is not the answer you are looking for, please edit your question and leave a comment to Subgeo that something still isn't quite right.  The green tick shows SO answerers that there is nothing left to solve and shows SO researchers that a correct answer has been provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it with the function [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) and a loop calling your function.

```
$file = "data.txt";
$website_url = "http://website.com/page.php?id=";

for(i = 1; i <= 1000; i++){
    file_put_contents($file, curl($website_url.i), FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ';' on line of for(i =0; i < 1000, i++){

Comment: Edited... Sorry

Comment: is there any chance of putting timer on this request. like for example to parse each link every 10 seconds.i did small modification $file = "email.txt";
$website_url = "https://www.example.com/page.php?lan=geo&id=";

for($i= 0; $i < 108400 ; $i++)

{
    
    curl($website_url.$i);
 $emails = preg_match('/<a href="mailto:(.*?)"/', $website_url.$i, $matches);
 echo $website_url.$i;
    file_put_contents($file, $matches[1] , FILE_APPEND);
}

?>

Comment: Yes, you can use [`usleep(x)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php) function to delay the execution by `x` microseconds.